# how to test on php if i am in scope global or not

Tags: scope

my question is how to test if i am on "scopeglobal" or not on magento 2 , with php

any help please ?

Comment: where and which scope you need to check? specify some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current store information using the [following code](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_storeManager;    

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get store identifier
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}

/**
 * Get website identifier
 *
 * @return string|int|null
 */
public function getWebsiteId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
}

/**
 * Get Store code
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStoreCode()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
}

/**
 * Get Store name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStoreName()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
}

/**
 * Get current url for store
 *
 * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
 * @return string     
 */
public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
}

/**
 * Check if store is active
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isStoreActive()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
}
}
?>
```

In a .phtml file of your module:

```
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
```